# Issue with Compass/Sass config.rb

Tags: configuration, sass, compass, urlhelper

I am trying to update my asset directories within my scss config.rb file.  I need to access compass mixins such as height: image-height($image);  For this to work, my images path has to be relative to my project’s image directory, defined in your config.rb file.  However, I cannot get this to work. I have used the compass url_helpers but nothing seems to be changing.  No matter how I update the assets in my config.rb, the following is returned when declaring an image variable in my scss..."No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /private/var/www/websites/gc/app/sites/all/themes/merge/scss/../images/../search-b-image.jpg"  Where is this ../images/.. coming from if its not in my config.rb?  Any help is much appreciated.

config.rb file is:

```
http_path = "/"

css_dir = "compiled_css"
sass_dir = "scss"
images_dir = "img"
javascripts_dir = "js"
environment = :development
relative_assets = true
output_style = :expanded

output_style = :compressed

preferred_syntax = :scss
```

Comment: What *is* the contents of your config.rb?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response.  I added my config.rb above.

Comment: That error shouldn't be possible based on your config.rb.  What's the `$image` variable contain?

Comment: The variable is simply $image: 'search-b-image.jpg';

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have another config.rb in your theme?

Comment: Thanks for the help, everyone.  I have to say I'm not sure what caused this.  I trashed the config.rb file and added a new one (exactly the same).  This was the third time I did this and this time it worked.  No clue what the issue was here.